# C# WPF изменить MouseButtonState

Tags: c#, wpf

Как мне убрать MouseButtonState.Pressed с кнопки мышки програмно? Т.е пользователь нажал на кнопку она стала MouseButtonState.Pressed мне нужно сделать ее Release, но свойства которые я нашел read only

Comment: Зачем? Расскажите о своей изначальной задаче

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите изменять состояния кнопок в обработчике события, то могу сказать, что это невозможно сделать, поскольку эти свойства, как вы и отметили, только для чтения.

Вы можете создать свое свойство с типом `MouseButtonState` и уже его изменять так, как вам захочется.

Если вы скажете, зачем вам это нужно, то мы найдем решение вашей проблеме.

**UPD.** Как отметил пользователь [D. Stark](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238013/d-stark), если очень хочется, можно изменить значение с помощью рефлексии.

Comment: Изменить можно через рефлексию например

Comment: Ладно, про рефлексию я забыл